# Azure Create SQL Database: Deployment validation failed

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a free SQL Database in Azure under my DreamSpark subscription but I repeatedly receive the following error:

[image: Error]

When you start an SQL Database creation, Azure lets you choose or create an SQL Server:

[image: sql database creation]

Since I don't currently have an Azure SQL Server I have to create one. I figured my error could be isolated to the server creation and effectively, while trying to create only the server, the error still rises.

I think that, even if Dreamspark subscription allows for a free small SQL Database, it does not allow for a free SQL Server. But this does not make any sense because I think there is no way to have an SQL Database without an SQL Server... So my questions:

1. Could you please confirm or refute my suspicion about Azure not permitting a free SQL Server in DreamSpark subscription?
2. In case it is not allowed, is there a way to create an SQL database without an SQL Server in Azure?
3. In case it is indeed allowed, why do I have this error then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up circumventing this problem by using visual studio 2017 to create DB and DB Server for me. So we can be sure that DreamSpark subscription allows for a small DB AND a DB Server creation, which makes sense.

Still, don't know why I was getting that weird error though.

While creating the db, visual studio changed the name I provided by concatenating "dbserver" and "_db" to the server and db respectively. Perhaps, there was a naming issue that VS solved automatically, and that Azure is not reporting correctly.